# How to check the type of a many-to-many-field in django?

Tags: python, django, django-models, manytomanyfield, manyrelatedmanager

How can you check the type of a many-to-many-field in django?

I wanted to do it this way:

```
import django  
field.__class__ == django.db.models.fields.related.ManyRelatedManager
```

This doesn't work, because the class `ManyRelatedManager` can't be found.
But if i do `field.__class__` the output is `django.db.models.fields.related.ManyRelatedManager`

Why does it refer to a class that doesn't seem to exist and how can i bring it to work?

Many thanks for your help.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you already have the field instance you can simply do:

```
if isinstance(field, ManyToManyField):
    pass // stuff
```

If you only have the related manager instance, you can reverse lookup the field instance:

```
>>> print fm
<class 'django.db.models.fields.related.ManyRelatedManager'>
>>> print fm.instance._meta.get_field_by_name('fieldnamehere')
(<django.db.models.fields.related.ForeignKey: fieldnamehere>, None, True, False)
```

This has only been tested on Django 1.5

Comment: This would be the perfect way, but i don't know how to get the field-instance of a many-to-many-field, that is located at the target-model.. if you could help me with this, i'll accecpt your answer :)

Comment: I can list all the fields with `object._meta.get_all_field_names()` but the corresponding fieldname isn't accessible via `object._meta.get_field('fieldname')`. I can use the function `object._meta.get_field_by_name('fieldname')` which puts out `(<RelatedObject: projectname:modelname1 related to modelname2>, None, False, True)`. Actually i don't know how to get the field-instance out of that..

Comment: got it :).. it is:
`object._meta.get_field_by_name("fieldname")[0].field`

Answer (score 20):

You should be able to check it as a string.

```
field.__class__.__name__ == 'ManyRelatedManager'
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response! But isn't that a little bit undynamic? Actually, i don't think that the class "ManyRelatedManager" will be ever renamed, but isn't it a little bit sloppy? But however, i think I'll use this answer, becuase it is more performant than lazerscience's one. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

(Using Django 1.11)

This question has become confusing, because the reported behavior is not the modern behavior for a related field. Example here, where `JobTemplate` is the model class, and `credentials` is a many-to-many related field:

```
>>> JobTemplate._meta.get_field('credentials').__class__
 django.db.models.fields.related.ManyToManyField
```

Is it different if we inspect the `_meta` of an object?

```
>>> JobTemplate.objects.first()._meta.get_field('credentials').__class__
django.db.models.fields.related.ManyToManyField
```

no.

So here's when I insert what I think is the most likely scenario of someone coming here. You have this:

```
>>> JobTemplate.objects.first().credentials
<django.db.models.fields.related_descriptors.ManyRelatedManager at 0x6f9b390>
```

Note, this is what the OP had.

I will stipulate that the related model is `Credential`. I can check if this is a related credential manager!

```
>>> isinstance(JobTemplate.objects.first().credentials, Credential.objects.__class__)
True
```

ManyToMany fields can be very hard to process, because the attribute kills itself and replaces itself with the manager sub-class. You could also cross-reference this information with the field obtained from `get_field('credentials')` to be extra sure. The above `isinstance` check could also erroneously pick up other managers that you have set on the model. However, this is still a valuable test to see if the attribute you have "quacks" how a ManyToMany field of that particular related model should.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure what you are trying to achieve, but i guess you should better look into your model's `_meta` attribute for determining the field class!
check out `_meta.fields` and `_meta.many_to_many`!

You could do something like:

```
field_class = [f for f in yourmodel._meta.many_to_many if f.name=='yourfield'][0].__class__
```