# How to check if a django model attribute is of type ManyToMany?

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have a django model in which I am inspecting the fields types and I want to check if a field is a ManyToMany field. When I call the type(attribute) function however, the returned type is a ManyRelatedManager object and not a ManyToManyField. This is a bit of a problem because I can't use the `isinstance(attribute, ManyRelatedManager)` because from what I see in the source code, this class is in a closure context and can't be accessed externally.

How would I check if a field in django is of type ManyToMany?
I checked out this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2849108/how-to-check-the-type-of-a-many-to-many-field-in-django) but this doesn't seem to be my scenario, I don't care what is the model of the ManyToMany I want to know if it is a many to many.

Comment: Can you share the code with us and show us where you are trying to check the type?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can work with your model:

```
isinstance(MyModel._meta.get_field('field_name'), ManyToManyField)
```